# Cannot modify a List Item/Element in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list that is initialised as follows:
This is outside of main (so it is global as many other classes need to access it).

```
List mainMenuList = [];
```

It is then populated with shopping items.

so

```
mainMenuList.elementAt[counter].shoppingPrice;
```

or

```
print(mainMenuList.elementAt[counter].shoppingPrice);
```

gives '4.00';

but if I wanted to increment or change that element's value, I get an error:

```
flutter: Unsupported operation: read-only
```

So, for example, I'm trying to add supplements to it:

```
mainMenuList[listItemIndicator]['ItemPrice'] += supplementsList[supplementCounter]['SupplementPrice']);
```

I get the following error:

flutter: Unsupported operation: read-only

So even if I forget about supplements.. if I did something like:

```
mainMenuList[listItemIndicator]['ItemPrice'] = 1.00;
```

I get the same error

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you share code for your list item class?

Comment: This is a bit hard to answer this because you don't explain what elements you add to `mainMenuList`.  We can deduce that `mainMenuList` *probably* stores `Map` objects, since you get a read-only error, those `Map` objects *probably* were constructed with [`Map.unmodifiable`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Map/Map.unmodifiable.html).  If so, then you'd need to either not use `Map.unmodifiable` or make a modifiable copy with [`Map.of`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Map/Map.of.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use key-value generic with `List` here or so the above code shows

```
mainMenuList[listItemIndicator]['ItemPrice'] = 1.00;   //incorrect way of using List
```

You need to use either `HashMap` or `LinkedMap` for that.

Comment: Hi. I don't understand why I can't access it directly through a list??

Comment: Please update your code with how you are populating the list. It would make more sense.

Comment: Hi Aziz, this is the code.. I have a list. it is built using list view builder. I want to change the price of an item in that list. That's all.. reading is ok.. but it won't allow me to write or change values in that list. Please help.