# Is there a problem, or is it bad accessing and changing values in a List?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List

```
List myList = [];
```

It gets populated with values, and then I go and I change these values. It works well.

But then it stopped working and I opened a question here, and a gentleman responded saying that I need to use HashMap, LinkedHash.. etc..

Why? I got it working again. Is it wrong?
Is it wrong to access a list and write to it?

I copied some code that I found on the net, and the developer had copied all elements into a Map and was accessing the elements via a Map object.

```
Map myMap ;

myMap = myList[0];
```

--> but frankly speaking, I really didnt see why I needed a Map variable. So I erased all Map variables, and my code works fine.

Am I doing something illegal? Or bad practice?

Comment: What you want to do is not very clear. Can you give a small code example showing what you mean by accessing and changing values?

Comment: If you're referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57799762/179715, then that answer is probably wrong advice, but it's unclear because the question it was answering was also unclear.

Comment: Yes.. and I think perhaps you have the right answer. The way in which this list was created could be the issue. Perhaps I removed the map part - which made it an unmodifiable list?